# Implementation of SIMCLR -keras-tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I am trying to implement this paper ['A Simple Framework for Contrastive Learning of Visual Representations'](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05709) in `google colab`. I tried to replicate this code found in [github](https://github.com/mwdhont/SimCLRv1-keras-tensorflow/blob/master/2_model_SimCLR.ipynb).

In 14 th cell executing this code,

`y_predict_test_before = SimCLR.predict(data_test)`
gives the following error. `ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'DataGeneratorSimCLR.DataGeneratorSimCLR'>, <class 'NoneType'>`

I made many changes in the way importing `keras` and `tensorflow` libraries, made changes in importing `Sequence` from `data_utils`. And also I tried to downgrade `python`'s version to 3.6 in `colab` for the required version of `pandas==0.22`. But it does'nt work. Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Try this https://keras.io/examples/vision/semisupervised_simclr/

Comment: @M.Innat,  yes, I tried this. But I have difficulties in converting my custom data of images which I load from the disk to tf dataset. I have no clue how to adapt this function prepare_dataset() to my custom data. I tried using tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator() But I get errors.